# equivalent statements of mathematical induction

Tags: abstract-algebra

My manual gives two equivalent statements of the  Principle of Mathematical Induction:

**I**: Every subset V of $\mathbb{N}$ satisfying

1. $0 \in V$
2. $n \in V \, \text{every time}\, k \in V \quad \forall k | 0 \le k \lt n$

is equal to the natural set: $V = \mathbb{N}$

**II**:
Every subset U of $\mathbb{N}$ satisfying

1. $0 \in U$
2. $k \in U ⇒ \sigma(k) \in U \quad \forall k$

is equal to the natural set: $U = \mathbb{N}$

where $\sigma$ is the successor function a 1-1 function defined in Peano's axiomes.

It states the hypothesis in I are weaker than those in II. I don't understand why it is considering **I** weaker than **II**.

The second hypothesis of **I** could be stated alternatively like this:

$\text{if }\, k \in V \text{ for each }\, k \text{ such that } 0 \le k \lt n, \, \text{then } n \in V \text{ as well}$

Comment: Does the worksheet say that it is "weak**er**" or that it is "weak" induction? I may be wrong but I believe the difference between the statements is that of strong vs. weak induction. In which case, the difference is just about how strong of a hypothesis you need involving $\sigma(.)$, not how strong it is as a method.

Comment: it says the I is more restrictive, but actually equivalent to II.

Answer (score 0):

For I you seem to have copied the second statement, "$n\in V$" every time $k\in V$  $\forall k|0\le k\le n$" incorrectly.  At least it doesn't make sense!  I think you meant "$\forall n\in V$ **if** $0\le k< n$ **then** $k\in V$".

Also, in II, $\sigma(k)\in U$ doesn't make sense *until* you have defined $\sigma$!  Is $\sigma$ the "successor function"?  That is, is $\sigma(k)= k+ 1$?

Comment: The OP appears to have addressed the definition of $\sigma(k)$ in an edit.

Comment: I think the first statement was supposed to be "if $\forall k$ s.t. $0\le k <n : k\in V$, then $n\in V$". I.e., the parts were in the wrong order.